# close opendir resource with fclose()

Tags: php

Warning from a php script

E_WARNING: fclose(): 6 is not a valid stream resource

```
if($handle = opendir($dir)){
//do stuff
if(is_resource($handle)){
    fclose($handle);
  }
}
```

searching for this gave some older bug reports in php, where the main concern was closedir() accepting resources, but it seems fclose() should accept a resource returned from opendir.

I haven't been able to find any general best practice about resource types in php, and how to properly close them.

What is the consequence of this warning ? do i get a memory leak or something alike?

Comment: Where did you find about thing that `fclose()` should accept `opendir()` result? It's different resource type in general

Comment: a bug report saying that it didn't give an appropiate error https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44246 
I suppose the warning i get could be the error that's been implemented now?

Comment: Pay attention to: what PHP version is in that bug? (__5.2__) what status is in that bug? (__closed__). Also, it's the first time when I see somebody tries to develop application, basing on _bugs_ and not _documentation_ (if I've got everything right)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Docs](https://www.php.net/opendir),You're suppousd to close a dir with `closedir($dh);`,

Like this:

```
<?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```